# Why use textview, occur NullPointerException on android?

Tags: java, android

I want to use `TextView`.

First, please check my source.

```
public void StringSSID() {
   TextView ssidText;
   ssidText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ssid);

   WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActivityNetworkInfo();

  String ssidview;
  int netType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType(); //Null Check

    if (netType == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
        ssidview = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
        Log.d(TAG, "StringSSID WIFI -> " + ssidview);
    } else if (netType == cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
        ssidview = "ethernet connected";
        Log.d(TAG, "StringSSID ETHERNET ->" + ssidview);

    } else {
        ssidview = "unable network";
        Log.d(TAG, "StringSSID unable network ->" + ssidview);

    }

    ssidText.setText(ssidview);
```

`StringSSID` called `onCreate`.

I want when My app start check network state, then show network state.

But `NullPointerException` attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

`ssidText.setText(ssidview)` is not null.
I check my log.

Why occur `nullpointerException`?

Comment: post your xml file where you have your textView

Comment: are you calling setContentView(); in onCreate?

Comment: check you textview id in xml and compare, whether it is same.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid crash by using if condition on textview and null pointer is the main problem in java so you always check null using if condition that your View is not null thn perform your desire task on that like below code you can check it

```
if(ssidText!=null)
{
ssidText.setText(ssidview);
}
```

and check the id your assign at xml is same as your getting by findViewById. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, but Idon't know why `ssidText` is null?  ssidText value is not null.

Comment: can you post your xml where you assigning id to TextView

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `ssidText` is null. You should verify that this has a value before you assign it because when retrieving views you can get a null value for a number of reasons. You should do:

```
if(ssidText != null){
   ssidText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ssid);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't know why `ssidText` is null?   I check log ssidText value

Comment: It could be because you didn't inflate your XML file, but it's hard to say without seeing your whole class and the XML file. If it solved your problem, you should accept the answer. Why it's null is a whole other issue.